# I'm animating a bezier array by moving the parent object. How can I export the resulting animation?

Tags: animation, modifiers, export, bezier-curves, transforms

So I'm trying to achieve an animation of a tank track. I followed this tutorial, which worked great!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfnfwrmMfJc

(TL;DW: make an array from individual track links around a bezier curve and move the parent, which results in movement of the track along the curve.)

here is my blender project:[image]

However, when exporting into an FBX and bringing into unity, all I get is the track staying still, with only the parent object moving.

[image]

Is there a way to "bake" or "apply" the transformation or motion of the treads in some way which would allow me to see the movement in unity as it is in blender?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures